# What would be more generic tags about latex-to-WYSIWYG produced document (differentiating "report-like" from "presentation-like" document)?

Tags: discussion, tagging

Yesterday I saw the [`{latex-to-word}` tag](https://tex.stackexchange.com/tags/latex-to-word/info) for the first time and decide to add this *tag wiki* (because there was none):

```
{latex-to-word} is for questions about conversion from TEX files to DOCX files (MSWord).
```

But now, I wonder if there is a tag for latex-to-word (*MSWord*), why not creating one for *OpenOffice/LibreOffice Writer* and also *PowerPoint*, *OpenOffice Impress*, *Keynote*...? **It's endless**.

`{latex-to-wysiwyg}` could be more generic tag but it cannot differentiate "report-like" document (produced by WYSIWYG softwares, e.g. *MSWord*, *OpenOffice/LibreOffice*, etc.) from "presentation-like" document (produced by WYSIWYG softwares, e.g. *MSPowerPoint*, *OpenOffice/LibreOffice*, etc.).

**So, any idea of two new tags able to differentiate conversion to "report-like" document (produced by WYSIWYG software) from conversion to "presentation-like" document?**

BTW, "`latex-to-word`" could be used to designate all "report-like" documents produced by WYSIWYG softwares, but it's maybe too much implicit...

*I know that probably most of people here don't understand the point of converting LaTeX to word but please avoid the discussion on this post* ;)

Comment: I vote for `latex-to-wysiwyg` :)

Comment: Yes it could be suffiscient ultimately because if it concerns PowerPoint, then the tag {beamer} will probabely be added too, which permits to make the distinction…

Comment: Given [tag:msword] exists I would have said [tag:latex-to-word] should be about word processors in general, I don't think it's a particularly useful tag anyway though, only 61 questions, a large minority of which are closed, a reasonable fraction could be retagged to just use [tag:pandoc] or [tag:tex4ht] and [tag:msword], and of the remaining maybe half of those aren't about wholesale filetype conversion.